# Python: How to do extra stuff when a specific attribute of an object is accessed?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class in Python:

```
class Foo(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

I'd like to do some extra stuff when I access 'a' but NOT 'b'. So, for example, let's assume that the extra stuff I'd like to do is to increment the value of the attribute:

```
> f = Foo()
> f.a # Should output 2
> f.a # Should output 3
> f.a # Should output 4
> f.b # Should output 2, since I want the extra behavior just on 'a'
```

It feels like there is a way through __getattr__ or __getattribute__, but I couldn't figure that out.

The extra thing can be anything, not necessarily related to the attribute (like print 'Hello world').

Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Django?

Comment: @abarnert It doesn't, I removed the tag.

Comment: You've made `a` and `b` members of the class `Foo` rather than of each instance of `Foo`. This means that all instances share a single copy. Is that intentional? If so, it makes the problem much harder…

Comment: It really doesn't make it harder - you just access and change the class variable from the property. The only issue is if you want the property to be accessible as ``Foo.a``.

Comment: @abarnert No that's not what it means. Attribute assignment on an instance creates/changes an instance attribute, regardless of a class attribute of the same name. Try your example. `f2.b` will be 2.

Comment: @Lattyware: Well, yes, but normally that's the point of a class member. Meanwhile, delnan, you're right.

Comment: @abarnert Indeed, but it's what the asker shows in the example.

Comment: @Lattyware: I think that's because the OP didn't actually want a class variable in the first place, not because he wanted a class variable that he could use as an instance variable. That's the kind of thing a beginner is orders of magnitude more likely to do by accident than intentionally.

Comment: @abarnert True, I completely agree, which is why I added the extra explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Lattyware: Just for fun, I added an answer showing how you actually would do the equivalent for a class variable. But I gave your answer a +1, and I think that's the one that should be accepted, because if the OP thinks he wants my answer, he's probably wrong…

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for all your efforts to clarify the question and provide good answers. For the question I asked, I got detailed and satisfactory answers. I guess the confusion was originated based on my intended question, not the one I asked. In fact, I have a Django model whose attributes are database fields. I wanted to do something each time I access a specific field in the DB. I didn't explicitly state this Django part to make to question more general for larger audience. Apparently that would be more clear and well-targeted. Anyways, thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [property](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), which can be used nicely as a decorator:

```
class Foo(object):
    _a = 2

    @property
    def a(self):
        Foo._a += 1
        return Foo._a - 1

    b = 2
```

The function is called whenever you try to access `foo_instance.a`, and the value returned is used as the value for the attribute. You can also define a *setter* too, which is called with the new value when the attribute is set.

This is presuming you want the odd set-up of class attributes you only ever access from instances. (`_a` and `b` here belong to the class - that is, there is only one variable shared by all instances - as in your question). A property, however, is always instance-owned. The most likely case is you actually want:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 2
        self.b = 2

    @property
    def a(self):
        self._a += 1
        return self._a - 1
```

Where they are instance attributes.

Comment: Is the property body by change missing two instances of `self._`?

Comment: You've made this an instance property, not a class property. (For example, what happens when you do `Foo.a`?)

Comment: @delnan: Actually, `self` won't work, it has to be `Foo`. Also, `_a` is misspelled as `a`…

Comment: @abarnert It's used as instance property in the example in the question. Chances are it's not intended to be a class property, which is a very exotic beast.

Comment: Indeed I missed out ``self._``, just me going a little too quick. given the example given was on an instance, I presumed the asker actually wanted this on an instance, but it is ambiguous.

Comment: @abarnert Supplying the start value as class attribute may be misleading, but it does work.

Comment: @delnan: It works if you want to copy the class attribute to an instance attribute the first time, but most beginners probably don't want class attributes that magically turn into instance attributes… although given what the OP gave us, maybe this on does…

Comment: @abarnert Most beginners I've seen using class attributes are actually mistaking is for a concise way to define (the moral equivalent of) instance attributes. In any case, no point in guessing. This answer is good, because it explains that decision rather than assuming one of the two is desired.

Comment: @Lattyware: Try your code with the OP's sample, then see what `f._a` and `Foo._a` give you.

Comment: @abarnert Indeed, I tested it before and was surprised when it updated the class variable, then I realise I tested the instance anyway. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you really do want the equivalent of `@property` for a class variable, you have to build the [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) yourself.

You almost certainly *don't* want to do this—see Lattyware's answer for how to make normal instance variables, and turn one of them into a `@property`.

But here's how you could do it:

```
class IncrementOnGetDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=None):
        self.val = initval
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        self.val += 1
        return self.val - 1
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.val = val

class Foo(object):
    a = IncrementOnGetDescriptor(2)
    b = 2
```

Now you can test it:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a
2
>>> Foo.a
3
>>>> f.a
4
```

Turning this into a `@classproperty` decorator is left as an exercise for the reader.

PS, this *still* isn't exactly like a normal class variable. Setting `Foo.a = 10` will replace your magic auto-incrementing value with a normal `10`, while setting `foo.a = 10` will update the class with an auto-incrementing `10` instead of storing an instance variable in `f`. (I originally had the `__set__` method raise `AttributeError`, because normally you'd want an auto-incrementing magic variable be read-only, but I decided to show the more complex version just to show all the issues you have to deal with.)

Comment: +1 for an informative post - just because the OP didn't want this doesn't mean someone else coming along won't.